# How To Insert (array values) More then 1 Value From Input Into 1 Row Of Database In Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, forms, input

I have a form like bellow with more then 1 Input in my form with 1 name like bellow:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="family">
<input type="text" name="inputCurrName[]">
<input type="text" name="inputCurrName[]">
<input type="text" name="inputCurrName[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and i have a table with 2 column with column name **Family** and **CurrName**

I want to save multiple names into one Row of CurrName Column in form submission , for example this is my data when submitted:

`Family Input: ali 
inputCurrName[] Inputs : array(jack,peter,lara)`

I want to save only 1 record in database with that data like:

```
familyColumn Value: ali | CurrNameColumn Value: {jack,peter,lara}
```

I have used code below but it save 3 record in database!

```
$input = $request->all();
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($input['inputCurrName']); $i++) {
  $user_data = [
    'family' => $input['family'],
    'curr_name' => $input['inputCurrName'][$i],
  ];

  User::Creat($user_data);
}
```

What should i DO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a `for loop` checking the length of `inputCurrName`, so it loops through each `inputCurrName`, which is why you are getting 3 records per `FamilyName`. In this case, you would only care about 1 record per `FamilyName`.

There are a few ways you can insert the `array` of `inputCurrName` values into 1 record with `FamilyName`.

You can use [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to create a storable representation of a value and [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to decode it when retrieving from the database.

-OR-

You can use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create a comma delimited list when inserting the record. And upon retrieval from the database, use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to iterate through each of the comma delimited values.

-OR-

If you prefer json you can do the same with [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the same way as serialize() and unserialize()

```
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| FamilyName |                        CurrName                         |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Ali        |  a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Laura";i:1;s:6:"Peter ";i:2;s:4:"Jack";} |
| Ali        |  Laura,Peter,Jack                                       |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using the following code will give you an example for the table above. `curr_name_optional` is part of the `$user_data` `array` to showcase implode().

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {

    $inputFamilyName  = $_POST['family'];
    $inputCurrentName = $_POST['inputCurrName'];

    // Your laravel code here..
    $user_data = [
      'family' => $inputFamilyName,
      'curr_name' => serialize($inputCurrentName),
      'curr_name_optional' => implode(',', $inputCurrentName),
      'curr_name_optional_1' => json_encode($inputCurrentName)
    ];

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user_data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>

<form method="post">
    Family Name: <input type="text" name="family"/> <br/>
    Curr Name: <input type="text" name="inputCurrName[]"/><br/>
    Curr Name: <input type="text" name="inputCurrName[]"/><br/>
    Curr Name: <input type="text" name="inputCurrName[]"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Also, I would make sure to trim and sanitize your form input data before inserting into the database.

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Woodrow  , all of your 3 ways worked! . which way is better and standard ?

Comment: Can You Tell Me How Can I Show serialize,implode,json_encode Data In Laravel Blade In Pretty View Like This?>> ```FamilyName:: Ali ,  CurrName:: Laura,Peter,Jack ```

Comment: I want to show in laravel blade like this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289138)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a foreach and then convert the data into json format then insert into a single row

```
$arr = [];
foreach($request->get('inputCurrName') as $key => $value){
   $arr[$key] => $value;
}
$user_data = [
      'family' => $request->get('family_name'),
      'curr_name' => json_encode($arr),
     ];

User::Create($user_data);
```

Not sure how its working but, you seem to forgot passing `csrf-token` in your form. Add `@csrf` just below the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Thank you , @Woodrow ways worked , and i have tested your solution but it has syntax error on ```$arr[$key] => $arr[$value];```