# How Can I Unserialize Or Json Decode Or Un Implode Data From Database In Laravel Blade?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, serialization, implode

I have saved data from a form with **Serialize** array and **Implode** and **Json_encode** like bellow:

> **Serialize**

```
+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Agent |                Customers               |                Cars                 |                 Money                  |
+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| SMITH |  a:2:{i:0;s:4:"Jack";i:1;s:4:"Mike";}  | a:2:{i:0;s:3:"BMW";i:1;s:4:"Audi";} | a:2:{i:0;s:5:"1000$";i:1;s:5:"1500$";} |
| ...   | ...                                    | ...                                 | ...                                    |
+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

> **Implode**

```
+-------+------------+----------+-------------+
| Agent |  Customers |   Cars   |    Money    |
+-------+------------+----------+-------------+
| SMITH |  Jack,Mike | BMW,Audi | 1000$,1500$ |
| ...   | ...        | ...      | ...         |
+-------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

> **Json_encode**

```
+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
| Agent |    Customers    |      Cars      |       Money       |
+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
| SMITH | ["Jack","Mike"] | ["BMW","Audi"] | ["1000$","1500$"] |
| ....  | ....            | ...            | ...               |
+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

I want to show data in admin panel like bellow:
Agent **SMITH** sold **BMW** car to **Jack** with **1000$** and **Audi** car to **Mike** with **1500$**

---------------------
How can i do this with 3 way **Unserialize, Unimplode and Json_decode** ?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: @Cid I coded with unserialize in laravel but i can't show the things that i want to be , when i have used unserialize it shows like this :: ```SMITH Jack MIKE BMW Audi 1000$ 1500$ ``` but i want like the string that i wrote : ```Agent SMITH sold BMW car to Jack with 1000$ and Audi car to Mike with 1500$ ```

Answer (score 0):

So  i am Considering Your Array

```
$yourArray = [
    'Agent' => 'SMITH',
    'Customers' => ["Jack", "Mike"],
    'Cars' => ["BMW", "Audi"],
    'Money' => ["1000$", "1500$"],
];
```

And Your Expected Output is

```
$yourExpectedOutPut = 'Agent SMITH sold BMW car to Jack with 1000$ and Audi car to Mike with 1500$';
```

So first import this to your name space

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$agentName = Arr::get($yourArray, 'Agent');
$customers = Arr::get($yourArray, 'Customers');
$cars = Arr::get($yourArray, 'Cars');
$Money = Arr::get($yourArray, 'Money');


    foreach ( $customers as $customerIndex => $customerName) 
    {
        $perparedArray[] = $cars[$customerIndex] . ' car to '. $customerName.' with '. $Money[$customerIndex];
    }

$preparedString = 'Agent '. $agentName.' sold '.implode(' and ', $perparedArray);

echo $preparedString;

Agent SMITH sold BMW car to Jack with 1000$ and Audi car to Mike with 1500$
```

if you have **any doubt** or **found any issues** or if the **answer is not what you are looking for** kindly comment below

Comment: I get data from database with this code in contoller: ```$table = TableName::all(); ``` and in blade in for each loop, I can return my column data but i can't make an array like ```$yourArray```

Comment: Can you share the table structure with some Data.So that I will dig deeper

Comment: My problem is that i can't make $yourArray array, can you please tell me how can i get data from database and make them like your $yourArray array?

Comment: for that you need to share the table structure with table data

Comment: I have solved My Problem , I have merged customers , cars and money table columns into one column and save into database as a 2D Array , inputs name should be like this ```inputArrName[Customers][] , inputArrName[Cars][] and inputArrName[Money][]``` and i userd Serialize method